# I am not able to set a custom Domain for my Hidden Service on Kali

Tags: onion-services, linux, url

I currently have tor installed on my Kali Linux laptop, I am trying to run a hidden service. Everything is working fine except I can't set a custom onion address. I have shallot installed and I already have my RSA private key for the domain I want. I keep putting the key inside:

```
/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/private_key
```

The key stays there, but doesn't apply to the hostname file. Even if I change the onion link in the hostname file itself, when I restart Tor, the hostname file changes back to the original onion link I got when I created my hidden service. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post your tor logs. Also check the permissions and ownership of the files in your onion service directory.

Comment: where are the tor logs?

Comment: That depends on how you installed tor. When installed using apt on Debian, you can see them with `journalctl -u tor@default`.